# Spring Data and ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data, hibernate-search, spring-data-elasticsearch, elasticsearch-model

I just started to create a app using Spring Data and Elasticsearch starter for spring boot.

My doubt is about the concept in true ... my first needs is create a type that will be able to save a lot of words.

First lets considering:

- I have a lot of files ( txt/csv ) file with about 5000 words each.
- The words has no relation one each other

So ...

**1** - If I create an entity it will be only one field (something like "name") and I'll need parse the file to get each word before send it to és.

**2** - If I save the entire document I'm afraid that it could affect the performance and maintenance of database in future.

What should I do? I am thinking on right way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: sorry but it's unclear what you need to achieve, so it's hard to suggest what you should do.

Comment: It's like a vocabulary, I Will need tô search for keywords matchs

Comment: Are you planning on using [Hibernate Search](http://hibernate.org/search/)? Your question is tagged `hibernate-search`, but you seem to be using the Spring Data Elasticsearch module, which is unrelated.